# Adding ppa for airvpn app eddie-ui

Tags: ppa, release-juno

i used to use airvpn in ubuntu and adding the ppa was easy with the graphical interface. I have experience adding ppa's through the terminal but this ppa doesnt seem to fit the right format...

deb http://eddie.website/repository/apt testing main

how would i structure the command?

Comment: Is the DEB installer package of Eddie not an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
wget -qO - https://eddie.website/repository/keys/eddie_maintainer_gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
```

followed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://eddie.website/repository/apt stable main"
```